# How to access view of layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an XML layout file that I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_dateStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Start Date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_dateEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="End Date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to access the layout and return a view of the layout from a method in a class that I wrote:

```
public class Utility {
 // 6 - LayoutInflate tool start
    public static View getViewOfLayout(Activity activity, int layoutId, int viewId) {
        LayoutInflater lin = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = lin.inflate(layoutId, null);
        view = view.findViewById(viewId);
        return view;
    }
    // LayoutInflate tool end
}
```

I also want to be able to access the view in the Activity class:

```
Button button = (Button) Utility.getViewOfLayout(this, R.layout.datedialogbox, R.id.button_ok);
            button.setText("a");
```

When I ran the code above, nothing happened: the text did not change from "OK" to "a" as expected.

Comment: When you say nothing happened, what do you mean? When you set break points in the code, are the values null? If so where, etc.

Comment: its mean text of button does not set to "ok",,, i set break point button values not null,,,

Comment: Why are you doing  it this way, for every view mapping, you are actually whole layout.

Comment: can you show some more code that you have used

Comment: You're creating a whole new copy of the layout every time you call that function.  You should only call inflate once-  when you first create that layout.  After that you should call findViewById either on the root view or on the activity to find the view.

Comment: @YakuZa I show all neccessry code to you ,, I want to access child view of xml layout file

Comment: @GabeSechan please write some changes to code ,, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

1. Update you `Utility.java` class as below:

   ```
   public class Utility {

       public static View getViewOfLayout(View layout, int viewId) {

           View view = layout.findViewById(viewId);
           return view;
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your `Activity` class:

   ```
   ..............
   ....................
   LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
   View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datedialogbox, null);

   Button button = (Button) Utility.getViewOfLayout(dialogLayout, R.id.button_ok);

   button.setText("BUTTON");
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               // Do something...
           }
       });


   ......................
   .............................
   ```

**If your purpose is to create a `Custom Dialog` then you can do it easily with minimal code as below:**

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
            AlertDialog dialog;

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datedialogbox, null);

            // Views
            final EditText editTextDateStart = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText_dateStart);
            final EditText editTextDateEnd = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText_dateEnd);
            Button button = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);

            button.setText("BUTTON"); // Change button text
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String dateStart = editTextDateStart.getText().toString();
                    String dateEnd = editTextDateEnd.getText().toString();

                    // Do something
                }
            });

            dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);

            dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanRafique: Please try my updated answer. Hope this will help you to fix your problem.